# Unable to cast object of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Object] in Dapper

Tags: c#, dapper

I can get data from the database using Dapper fine. But when I try to cast it into an IEnumerable, I get the error:

```
System.InvalidCastException: 'Unable to cast object of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Object]' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[ITMS.Shared.Incident]'.'
```

Please see how I implement the fetching of data:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<Incident>> GetIncidents(string authorId)
{
    try
    {
        using var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        var parameters = new DynamicParameters();
        parameters.Add("@Mode", 3);
        parameters.Add("@AuthorId", authorId);
        var incidents = await connection.QueryAsync(
            sql,
            param: parameters,
            commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);
        return (IEnumerable<Incident>)incidents; => I GET THE ERROR HERE
    }
    catch (Exception ew)
    {
        throw;
    }
}
```

My query is just a straight forward SELECT Statement.

Comment: Using `catch (Exception ew) { throw, }` is a bad idea. You're catching an exception and just returning it. Don't bother catching it if you don't want to handle it. The `try/catch` construct in .NET is optimized so that setting up a try block is very efficient, but the actual catch is quite slow. Here you get to catch it twice!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use `QueryAsync<T>()` method in order to return `IEnumerable<T>`. `QueryAsync()` supports dynamic type which returns `IEnumerable<object>`.

Reference: [Querying Multiple Rows With Dapper](https://www.learndapper.com/dapper-query/selecting-multiple-rows)

```cs
var incidents = await connection.QueryAsync<Incident>(
            sql,
            param: parameters,
            commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);

return incidents;
```